# I'm using mongorepository and mongotemplate is it true that it opens two connection?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using mongorepository and mongotemplate is it true that it opens two connection?

Is it good practice? i am using spring boot 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the each use their own connection. Yes, it’s good practice.

Mongodb driver maintains a mongodb connection pool. As a thread (whether using template or repo) needs a connection it is made available, used and returned to the pool. Typically a server will have multiple simultaneous connections in use, even if only using template (or only using repo). The mongodb driver manages this.